# Generalize haskell function

Tags: generics, haskell

I should write function that takes list, element and return positions in with such element occurs. Like,

```
pos 2 [1, 2, 3, 2] -> [2, 4]
pos 1 [1, 2, 3, 2] -> [1]
pos 8 [1, 2, 3, 2] -> []
```

This what I've done.

```
--findFirstPosition :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
findFirstPosition val xs = case f of 
    Nothing -> Nothing 
    Just (v, i) -> Just(i)
  where f = (find (\ (v, i) -> val == v) (zip xs [1..]))

--pos :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
pos _ [] = []
pos val xs = if (finded) 
    then concat[
           [fromJust res],
            map (\a -> a + (fromJust res)) 
            (pos val (drop  (fromJust res) xs))]
    else []  
  where 
    res = findFirstPosition val xs
    finded = (isJust res)
```

It's works quite good. But when I'm trying to use functions type (like shown in comments)  error occurs

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
from the context (Eq a)
  bound by the type signature for pos :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
  at \test.hs:(63,1)-(72,29)
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for pos :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
      at \test.hs:63:1
Expected type: Maybe Int
  Actual type: Maybe a
In the first argument of `fromJust', namely `res'
In the first argument of `drop', namely `(fromJust res)'
```

How should I deal with it? Also any additional code review comments are highly appreciated.

**Upd**
I should implement it using `find` function.

Comment: Note: please indent your code with spaces, not tabs (at least on SO, the code formatter here doesn't like tabs at all).

Comment: Some hints for improvements: Let us consider the following expression `concat [[fromJust res], map (\a -> a + (fromJust res)) (pos val (drop  (fromJust res) xs))]`. This expression has the form `concat [[e1], e2]`. Check what `concat` yields for an argument of this form. Furthermore you could define a shortname for the expression `fromJust res` as it occurs several times.

Comment: @Jan Christiansen, thanks I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `findFirstPosition` should be

```
findFirstPosition :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

The purpose of this function is to find a position, or index. So the return type should wrap something appropriate for indexing, but independent of the argument type(s).

Unrelated: are you sure that indexing should start with 1? Usual is 0-based indexing.

Comment: It's just exercise, so it doesn't really meter with base it is) I'll accept this answer as soon as it will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this much more consisely using a list comprehension.

```
pos :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
pos y xs = [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs, y == x]
```

I also changed it to use zero-based indices for consistency with other list functions, but you can easily adjust this to 1-based if you need that.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I should use `find` in this task. Sorry that I didn't mentioned this.